# How to prevent data duplication caused by LiveData observation in Fragment?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata

I'm subscribed to an observable in my Fragment, the observable listens for some user input from three different sources.

The main issue is that once I navigate to another Fragment and return to the one with the subscription, the data is duplicated as the observable is handled twice.

What is the correct way to handle a situation like this?

I've migrated my application to a Single-Activity and before it, the subscription was made in the activity without any problem.

Here is my Fragment code:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class ProductsFragment : Fragment() {
    @Inject
    lateinit var sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences

    private var _binding: FragmentProductsBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    private val viewModel: ProductsViewModel by viewModels()
    private val scanner: CodeReaderViewModel by activityViewModels()

    private fun observeBarcode() {
        scanner.barcode.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { barcode ->
            if (barcode.isNotEmpty()) {
                if (binding.searchView.isIconified) {
                    addProduct(barcode) // here if the fragment is resumed from a backstack the data is duplicated.
                }

                if (!binding.searchView.isIconified) {
                    binding.searchView.setQuery(barcode, true)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun addProduct(barcode: String) {
        if (barcode.isEmpty()) {
            return
        }

        viewModel.insert(barcode)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        viewModel.start(args.documentId)

        if (args.documentType == "Etichette") {
            binding.cvLabels.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }

        initUI()
        observe()
    }

    private fun observe() {
        observeBarcode()
        observeProducts()
        observeLoading()
        observeLast()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, LiveData is a terribly bad idea (the way it was designed), Google insisted till they kinda phased it out (but not really since it's still there) that "it's just a value holder"...

Anyway... not to rant too much, the solution you have to use can be:

1. Use The "SingleLiveEvent" (method is officially "deprecated now" but... [you can read more about it here](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/livedata-with-snackbar-navigation-and-other-events-the-singleliveevent-case-ac2622673150)).
2. Follow the "official guidelines" and use a Flow instead, as described [in the official guideline for handling UI Events](https://developer.android.com/topic/architecture/ui-layer/events).

#### Update: Using StateFlow

The way to collect the flow is, for e.g. in a Fragment:

```
       viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
            repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) { // or RESUMED
                viewModel.yourFlow.collectLatest { ... } // or collect { ... }
            }
        }
```

For that in your `ViewModel` you'd expose something like:

*Warning: Pseudo-Code*

```
// Imagine your state is represented in this sealed class
sealed class State {
   object Idle: State
   object Loading: State
   data class Success(val name: String): State
   data class Failure(val reason: String): State
}

    // You need an initial state
    private val _yourFlow = MutableStateFlow(State.Idle) 
    val yourFlow: StateFlow<State> = _yourFlow
```

Then you can emit using

```
_yourFlow.emit(State.Loading)
```

Comment: I'm trying to rewrite it by using the StateFlow, the main issue is that by settings the value in activity to `barcode` as StateFlow and observing it in Fragment, the value is not emitted, shouldn't I use the StateFlow between that kind of communication?

I'm trying to listen for the value as this: https://imgur.com/b4qDoLY

Comment: I've updated the answer to give you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you call

```
scanner.barcode.observe(viewLifecycleOwner){
}
```

You are creating a new anonymous observer. So every new call to observe will add another observer that will get onChanged callbacks. You could move this observer out to be a property. With this solution observe won't register new observers.

Try

```
class property
val observer = Observer<String> { onChanged() }

inside your method
scanner.barcode.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, observer)
```

Alternatively you could keep your observe code as is but move it to a Fragment's callback that only gets called once fex. onCreate(). onCreate gets called only once per fragment instance whereas onViewCreated gets called every time the fragment's view is created.